# How do I fix a MySQL due to Only Full Group Mode issue?

Tags: mysql

I recently upgraded to 5.7 of MySQL.

The query below is throwing the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.GroupLeader, SUM(gm.is_pending = 'N') AS MemberCount
          FROM org_group og
     LE' at line 1
```

Here is the query:

```
   SELECT og.group_id, og.group_name, CONCAT_WS(' ', m.first_name, m.last_name) AS GroupLeader, SUM(gm.is_pending = 'N') AS MemberCount
          FROM org_group og
     LEFT JOIN org_group_member gm ON og.group_id = gm.group_id
     LEFT JOIN org_group_member gm2 ON og.group_id = gm2.group_id
     LEFT JOIN member m ON gm2.member_id = m.member_id
         WHERE og.org_id = ?
           AND gm2.is_group_leader = 'Y'
      GROUP BY og.group_id
      ORDER BY og.group_name ASC
```

I understand that MySQL wants the query more definitively defined, but my attempts to add GroupLeader and MemberCount to the order by clause to correct the issue have not worked thus far.

Clearly I am missing how to form the syntax properly.  Please help.

Comment: First fix the syntax error. You can't use `og.GroupLeader` as column alias.

Comment: thanks Paul, you are correct.  That was one of my lame attempts to fix the issue.  I have removed the og. from GroupLeader in my example.  However, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was not putting GroupLeader first in the Group By clause.  Doing so corrected the problem.

```
SELECT og.group_id, og.group_name, CONCAT_WS(' ', m.first_name, m.last_name) AS GroupLeader, SUM(gm.is_pending = 'N') AS MemberCount
          FROM org_group og
     LEFT JOIN org_group_member gm ON og.group_id = gm.group_id
     LEFT JOIN org_group_member gm2 ON og.group_id = gm2.group_id
     LEFT JOIN member m ON gm2.member_id = m.member_id
         WHERE og.org_id = ?
           AND gm2.is_group_leader = 'Y'
      GROUP BY GroupLeader, og.group_id
      ORDER BY og.group_name ASC
```